# how can I use the id that I received via telegram?

Tags: python, kotlin, aiogram

I am writing an application linked to telegrams, I wrote a bot that creates an entry in the telegram user database, after adding the apk to the bot database, how do I make the data that I created used in the application?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['send_apk'])
async def send_apk(msg: types.Message):
    user_id = msg.from_user.id
    apk_file_path = "Dionis" 
    with open(apk_file_path, 'rb') as apk_file:
        await bot.send_document(user_id, apk_file)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['bind_apk'])
async def bind_apk(msg: types.Message):
        apk_file_name = msg.text.split()[1]
        user_id = str(msg.from_user.id)

        apk_id = str(msg.from_user.id)

        apk_ref = fb.reference('/apkFiles/' + apk_id)
        apk_ref.child("telegramUserId").set(user_id)

        await msg.reply("Success")
```

```
        myRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val userId = snapshot.child("telegramUserId").getValue(String::class.java)
                if (userId != null) {
                    tv.text=userId
                    telegram.sendMessage(userId, userId)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
```

the code in question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a bot, it creates an entry in firebase, the task of the application is to use the user ID from the database, the user is specified in the database as follows: user->user_id: 1338289092 I need data from firebase to install in the application in TextView

Answer (score 0):

If I've got you right, your TG bot populates data (particulary userId) to firebase storage, now you want to set that userId to TextView in your android app.

You need to specify full referency to your child like this `"apkFiles/your_user_id/telegramUserId"` or this `.child("apkFiles").child("your_user_id").child("telegramUserId")`
see example below:

```
textView = findViewById(R.id.userTextView)

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("apkFiles/your_user_id/telegramUserId")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                // Read value from the snapshot
                val userId = dataSnapshot.getValue(String::class.java)
                if (userId != null) {
                    textView.text = userId
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
 
            }
        })
```

Comment: I did this, I don't understand exactly how to get "your_user_id"

Comment: I don't know what's your Firebase structure, I'm just assuming that it should be 'apk_id' according to your code.
You can start from the root
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("apkFiles")
And then in onDataChange check values you will get, it might give you some hints.